# Change the value of autoincrement in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, auto-increment

I have developed the application using hsqldb and JPA/Hibernate. As per the client's request they wanted us to do some basic data entry (via file upload) so that they have the data till date when the start the application. And we did that as well.

Now the problem is that when I installed the application on the client end, they were not able to add any of the master data (neither the transaction data). I found that while adding the data hibernate gives org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException, which is because it starts inserting the values from 1.

So, I have set the GeneratorValue field with Auto. (@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)).

Should you need more information, please let me know. Any help will be highly appreciated.
(I have googled but did not find any specific answer so far)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you marked the column in your db engine to be auto increment ?

Answer (score 0):

Best preferred solution is to define a `sequence` in your database. Use the [**sequence generator**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.2/api/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/xml/jaxb/GenerationType.html#SEQUENCE) in Hibernate mapping. Don't populate the `Id` attribute manually.  Let hibernate take care of it. It will never give you unique constraint.

Also you my try to define a `custom generator` and write small logic to get unique ids to be used.